google news word2vec - 3 million 300-dimension vectors, but only 6908 distinct dimension numbers - why?
This google news word2vec dataset:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XkCwpI5KDYNlNUTTlSS21pQmM/edit?resourcekey=0-wjGZdNAUop6WykTtMip30g
google news word2vec - supposedly has has 3 million 300-dimension vectors. Each dimension could be from -1 to 1 floating point number.
ex:
-0.1728515625
 0.034912109375
 0.00897216796875
-0.0003261566162109375


So I would expect there would be huge number of unique dimensions, like 3mln*300 = 900mln unique vector dimensions.
However - when I actually scan the google news data and count all the unique dimensions - there is only 6908 unique dimensions...
Why is that?  What is in word2vec model that makes it produce such tiny number of dimensions?

This looks like it might b an interesting observation, but it is a bit unclear what you counted as "number of dimensions" is not a usual phrase. Could you add some small example?
